# How to disable pickle.loads for security?

Tags: python, pickle

For security reasons I would like to disable `pickle.loads` in a Python process.  I would like to continue being able to use `pickle.dumps` however.

Is there a standard way to achieve this?

To be clear I am not concerned about my user being malicious.  However I am concerned that they may inadvertently use library code that triggers `pickle.loads` in unexpected ways.

Comment: Monkeypatch it? `pickle.loads = lambda *_: raise Exception("No you don't")`? What does "disable" mean, exactly?

Comment: `del pickle.loads` in your main script

Comment: I don't know of a standard way to do it, and people can always subvert it by using the import library to load the module on their own. If you control the environment you could edit `pickle.py` itself.

Comment: Monkey patching is probably good in most situations.  However if someone grabs the pickle.loads function before my modification code runs, like with `loads = pickle.loads`, then it may not suffice?

Comment: If someone uses `pickle.loads` before you patch it then they can do evil things with it, yes. There isn't really anything you can do about that, except maybe search every imported module's globals for a reference to `pickle.loads`... but that sounds like overkill. Better just find a way to run your patch before anything can happen.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about a standard way, but depending on your use case one idea that comes to mind would be to overwrite the function:

```
pickle.loads = '_disabled'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that patching like `pickle.loads = disabled` where `disabled` raises some exception is the easiest. If you are really worried about the function being cached before you have a chance to clear it, you could patch the function pointer directly with something like:

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <methodobject.h>

/**
   Patch the c implementation of a `builtin_function_or_method`.

   @param ob The builtin_function_or_method object to patch.
   @param new_meth The new C function pointer to use.
   @param new_flags The new flags to set.
   @param old_meth pointer to store the old function pointer in. If this
          function fails, this value will be unchanged. If this value is `NULL`,
          it will not be stored.
   @param old_meth pointer to store the old function pointer in. If this
          function fails, this value will be unchanged.
   @param old_flags A pointer to store the old flags in. If this function fails,
          this value will be unchanged. If this value is `NULL`, it will not be
          stored.
   @return zero if the method was patched succesfully, non-zero on failure. If
           this function returns non-zero, an exception will be raised.
*/
static int patch_c_function(PyObject* ob,
                            PyCFunction new_meth,
                            int new_flags,
                            PyCFunction* old_meth,
                            int* old_flags) {
    if (!PyCFunction_Check(ob)) {
        PyErr_Format(PyExc_TypeError,
                     "expected builtin_function_or_method object, got: %s",
                     Py_TYPE(ob)->tp_name);
        return -1;
    }

    PyCFunctionObject* function_object = (PyCFunctionObject*) ob;

    if (old_meth) {
        *old_meth = function_object->m_ml->ml_meth;
    }
    function_object->m_ml->ml_meth = new_meth;

    if (old_flags) {
        *old_flags = function_object->m_ml->ml_flags;
    }
    function_object->m_ml->ml_flags = new_flags;
    return 0;

}

static PyObject* disabled(void) {
    PyErr_SetString(PyExc_AssertionError,
                    "this function is disabled in this process");
    return NULL;
}

static PyObject* disable_function(PyObject* self, PyObject* f) {
    if (patch_c_function(f,
                         (PyCFunction) disabled,
                         METH_VARARGS | METH_KEYWORDS,
                         NULL,
                         NULL)) {
        return NULL;
    }
    Py_RETURN_NONE;
}

PyMethodDef methods[] = {
    {"disable_function", (PyCFunction) disable_function, METH_O, NULL},
    {NULL},
};

PyModuleDef cext_module = {
    PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT,
    "cext",
    NULL,
    -1,
    methods,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL
};


PyMODINIT_FUNC
PyInit_cext(void) {
    return PyModule_Create(&cext_module);
}
```

This can then be used in a repl like:

```
In [1]: import pickle

In [2]: loads = pickle.loads

In [3]: from cext import disable_function

In [4]: disable_function(pickle.loads)

In [5]: pickle.loads()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-95a055f9ba4f> in <module>()
----> 1 pickle.loads()

AssertionError: this function is disabled in this process

In [6]: loads()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-73007b0e1946> in <module>()
----> 1 loads()

AssertionError: this function is disabled in this process
```